# Why loadCache always return false?

Tags: cache

I enable cache for my custom block by adding `cache_lifetime` in `__construct` and adding `getCacheKeyInfo()` function.

`cache_lifetime` and cach key were added successfully, I verified by going to `_loadCache` function in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and dump `$this->getCacheLifetime()` (shows `86400`), dump `$cacheKey` (shows `4bdf58570c6cc1c082c0a2309d0acbee3f318d90`)

But when I dump `$cacheData = $this->_getApp()->loadCache($cacheKey);`, it always return `false`.

Why does it return `false`? I haven't ever modified any core Mage files.

By the way, I'm using `apc` for backend cache, and `memcache` for session cache. CE 1.8.1.
And of course, I've enabled cache in admin panel already.

**UPDATE:**

Dump `$this->getCacheKey();` in `_loadCache()`: `cb2336b7ccd507da70b5167dcb7e87856284647d`

Dumo `$this->getCacheKey();` in `_saveCache()`: `00db354e5f03e1bf0b06da33c491eb2e313d29cc`

OMG. Where make it change?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out why.

This is my getCacheKeyInfo function.

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'MY_BLOCK_NAME',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
    }
```

When it calls `getCacheKeyInfo()` the first time in `_loadCache()`, I don't know why template is not initiated, so `$this->getTemplate()` return `null`.

At the second time of calling in `_saveCache()`, ( `_saveCache()` is called after `>_beforeToHtml();` and `_toHtml();`) then template is initiated, so `$this->getTemplate()` return path of template file.

I try to add template data in constructor of my block class (`$this->addData(array('template' => $this->getTemplate()));`), but it still doesn't work.

So, after all, I delete template element in cache key array.

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'MY_BLOCK_NAME',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
    }
```

It works now!

**UPDATED:**

OMG! I found out why template name is not initiated at the first time.

Because: My module set template in `_toHtml()` function, not in constructor (by adding `template="path/to/template/file.phml"`)